# How Can I Make The Right & Bottom Sides of My Div Appear Like the Top & Left Sides?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML & CSS. I have a div called `frame` inside the body of my webpage. Since the default position of `frame` is in the top left corner, when I change the width & height properties, `frame` extends to the right and bottom of the web page. Instead, I would like to see a border all the way around `frame` instead of just across the top, and down the left side. I've included my HTML & CSS below.

```css
body{
    background-color: #006487;
}

.frame{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My first attempt to scale back the `frame` div was to set the `height` & `width` properties of `frame` in px. This idea "works", but doesn't scale to different size monitors. The next thing I tried was adding `margin: 10px;` to the frame div, but this didn't format `frame` as I expected.

Comment: `height` & `width` can't be 100% AND have a 10px margin... it adds up to more than 100%

Answer (score 0):

The `.frame` element is offset by a margin, but is also 100% of the width and height of its parent (the `body`).  So it's wider and taller than the window.

You can make it smaller by using `calc()` in CSS.  For example:

```css
body{
    background-color: #006487;
}

.frame{
    height: calc(100% - 36px);
    width: calc(100% - 36px);
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">
        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

(Note: I arrived at the value of `36px` because my browser adds an `8px` margin to `body` plus your `10px` margin on `.frame`, doubled to account for each side.  You'll probably want to explicitly control the margin on `body` in case other users have different styling.)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this:

1. Using min-height and the `calc` function to subtract 20px from the viewport height (top and bottom padding)

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

body{
    background-color: #006487;
    padding: 10px;
}

.frame {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
    background-color: white;
}
```

2. Alternatively use a 10px border with the colour of the body tag and set `box-sizing: border-box;`

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.frame{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid #006487;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With both options you will need to remove the default margin and padding (for cross-browser consistency) that browsers will automatically set on HTML elements: `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`
The * selector will select all elements, place this at the top of your CSS file. All other styles that follow it will overwrite this setting.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have used absolute, but the result you needed can be done simply without using absolute positioning, please have a look at the code snippet below

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%; // set initial height to both html & body tag, otherwise body height will not be what you are expected
  margin: 0; // reset to 0
}

body{
    background-color: #006487;
    padding: 10px;
}

.frame{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="frame">  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```